# Specifying arguments in launch.json for Python

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to specify arguments in my `launch.json` file for debugging. I know I can do the following:

```
"args": ["--arg1", "value", "--arg2"]
```

However, I have a very long list of arguments that is formatted as a space-delimited string. Something like this: `"--arg1 value --arg2"`. I tried specifying:

```
"args": ["--arg1 value --arg2"]
```

But that didn't work. Right now my workflow is to take the string of arguments, run it through a Python script that changes the string into a list and copy paste it in my `launch.json` file. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you feed the arguments to CS Code in the proper form? How much work would that be?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Mind that providing arguments in `launch.json` works like described until you need key value args.

For example, the command

```
$ python main.py --verbose --name Test
```

has to be coded inside the *launch.json* arguments line like this:

```
"args": ["--verbose", "--name=Test"],
```

Find a nearly hidden hint in the "Watson" example in *[Python debug configurations in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging)*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For everyone wondering, if you need to add paths you might have to change "\" to "/" otherwise VSCode might not be able to read it properly.

Answer (score 22):

AAargh.. I just wasted 30 minutes of my life trying to figure out how to clearly define arguments with values. Sometimes things worked and sometimes total fail.  I was just looking at the last error message:  `// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.`

Turns out I had both my python program and the file launch.json active in the VScode open editor.  I was making changes to launch.json, but FAILING to click on my python file before starting up the debugger.

Doh! Its not a surprise that a python interpreter fails when trying to run a .json file.  Need to carefully read the complete error message.  (The error message should say... hey you big dummy.. you should be using a .py file when executing python!)

Info shared here in case anybody else makes the same dumb mistake.

Comment: This post was actually very helpful for me. You need to focus the file you would like to debug, then hit F5. Thanks!

Comment: Peter Mortensen, Really?  Your edit, two years after posting this answer was just inappropriate, and just not helpful.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: Technically, this doesn't answer the original question at all. However, it was exactly the piece of information I actually needed. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do what you want. Arguments can only be passed as an array, but not as a string with spaces. The argument with spaces is wrapped in quotation marks and passed as one whole argument.

Quote from the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes):

> args - arguments passed to the program to debug. This attribute is of
> type array and **expects individual arguments as array elements**.

Answer from one of the developers on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23527#issuecomment-290229557):

> The rule to translate a command line to the "args" is simple: every command line argument separated by whitespace needs to become a separate item of the "args" attribute.

**Examples:**

```
Command:
tar -cvf test-14-09-12.tar /home/test/

Args:
"args": ["-cvf", "test-14-09-12.tar", "/home/test/"]
```

```
Command:
tar -c --file new.tar --include='*foo*' old.tgz

Args:
"args": ["-c", "--file", "new.tar", "--include='*foo*'", "old.tgz"]
```

**Update:**

I found solution, using snippets.

You can add snippet to global snippets or project snippets, as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets):

```json
"args_transform": {
    "scope": "jsonc",
    "prefix": "args_transform",
    "body": "${1/((\"(.*?)\")|('(.*?)')|([^ ]+))( )?/\"$3$6$5\"${7:+, }/g}"
}
```

Write args_transform where you need to write args in launch.json (or any other json with comments file), press tab, insert your args and then press tab again

**But it, probably, not works correctly with some kind of arguments, please write errors in comments if snippet fix needed**

Comment: it'd be so nice to list some examples since this is the accepted answer :)  (I understand these are listed in a separate answer below)

Comment: Thanks, it;s working with this command in Windows.
"args": ["-cvf", "test-14-09-12.tar", "\\home\\test"]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
"args": [   "-arg1 value1",
            "-argname2 value2"],
```

It works with my PowerShell named arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't much, but it is honest work:

```py
import json

input_args = "--arg1 value --arg2"

vscode_args = list(input_args.split(" "))
print(json.dumps(vscode_args))
```

This prints:

```sh
["--arg1", "value", "--arg2"]
```

which you can paste in your *launch.json* file.

I made this because I have a lot of arguments to convert. This comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

I defined a variable ('workspace_path') for the debugger I'm using (launcher).

Settings -> Extensions -> Robot Framework -> Robot Variables [Robot: Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiVke.jpg)

Edit file 'settings.json' -> [settings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbwQG.jpg) and add the variable (example: 'workspace_path')

Run -> Open Configurations -> Edit file 'launch.json' [launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2jAB.jpg) and add the argument workspace_path (without cuotes).