# problems with debugging in .vscode

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug c++ code in vs-code and needs to pass argument to start debugging. to run the program in command line its just like that:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ ./hello-world 10
```

how to configure input parameter when debugging?
thanks for help in advance.

Comment: For better debugging purpose i suggest to use an IDE rather than Editor.

Comment: The file you need to edit is `launch.json` related: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_environment) and [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340968/specifying-arguments-in-launch-json-for-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46340968/specifying-arguments-in-launch-json-for-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can run it like that :

```
devenv /debugexe 'program name' 'program arguments'
```

Or use your IDE and define your arguments , all what you need is here =>

[Debugging with command-line parameters in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298708/debugging-with-command-line-parameters-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Actually I am using visual studio code on linux.

Comment: Just open your Visual Studio then right-click the project, choose Properties, go to the Debugging section there is a box for "Command Arguments" and then you start debugging